# Как найти переменную let в контексте событий?

Tags: javascript

Выводу контекст событий, там сразу вверху видно переменные a12 и a13 но переменные r221d1 и re не могу найти, почему их там нет?

```
var a12=15;
    let r221d1=35;
    re=35;
    var a13=234;
    console.log(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменная `re` будет определена глобально.

А что касается переменной `r221d1`, то в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) четко сказано, что `let`, в отличии от `var`, не создаёт свойства на глобальном объекте.